# AU Visitor visa (subclass 600) Business Visitor stream: National ID card and other passports/documents for travel

Tags: visas, paperwork, australia, identity-cards

I am a citizen of the Russian Federation. Currently, I work and have my family in Germany (permanent residency). In order to apply for a Visitor visa (subclass 600) Business Visitor stream, I should provide

- a national identity card
- the information on other passports/documents for travel.

(1) According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_identity_card_policies_by_country),

> a national identity document is defined as an identity card with
>   photo, usable as an identity card at least inside the country, and
>   which is issued by an official authority.

From my understanding, the permanent residence permit fulfills these requirements and is a national identity card (my citizenship is clearly stated there). In Russia, we have an internal passport that is not a card.

Am I right in understanding that as a national identity card I should provide my German permanent residence permit only?

(2) Other passports or documents for travel [include](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-text/eplus/Pages/elp-h2305.aspx):

> any expired passports or documents for travel where the details are
>   known.

In the online application, I am asked to

> Give details of any other non United Nations passports or documents for travel that might have been previously used to travel to Australia.

I have never been to Australia and never applied for an AU visa previously. However, in my understanding, my previous expired passport might have been used for an AU visa application - in theory (however, has not been). Should I provide information about my expired passport?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you unsure whether someone has applied for an Australian visa on _your_ old passport? Or are you just saying that it was once _possible_ for you to make such an application, but _you did not in fact do so_?

Comment: Also, I hope you're aware that you'll need _a passport_ to travel to Australia. A German residence card cannot be used instead of a passport.

Comment: @HenningMakholm (i) the second variant; (ii) yes, I'm aware of it.